# C/makefile, want to check 2 different dirs and copy subdirs if not existing. how?

Tags: c, makefile, merge, directory, cp

I will try explain here:
I want in makefile/c, do like copy from dir A -> dir C, and copy dir B -> dir C (**only if the subdir doesnt exist in B**! AND the othersubs/files are updated). I do not want to force copy cause that will trigger "change" and rebuild will be triggered for files which I dont want.

NOTE! Both A and B can have same subdirs. So could be like a merge of newest if any.

So some similiar to:
`cp -ur ./A ./C`
`cp -ur ./B ./C`

NOTE!
Do I need to do some for-statement and copy if not exists in B?
How to do that?
Like:
`for dir in A C` (but how to comapre with B ?)

Answer (score 0):

The [`file(COPY ...)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/file.html#copy) command should serve your purposes:

```
file(COPY ./A
     DESTINATION ./C)
file(COPY ./B
     DESTINATION ./C)
```

It always works recursively, and it will effectively do an update, as is written on that page:

> Copying preserves input file timestamps, and optimizes out a file if it exists at the destination with the same timestamp.

Comment: Oh nice, I will try and see if this command is possible for me in the environment.

Comment: BUT, will this not be like, IF the A subdirs are newer to the B subdirs then A will be used even if they exists in B?  This must not happen. Feels like this is the exactly same as: cp -ur ./A ./C cp -ur ./B ./C  ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean - is it if directory `A/Z` is newer, but `A/Z/foo`, `A/Z/bar` have the same timestamps as `B/Z/foo`, `B/Z/bar` you don't want anything copied? Or is it , as your code below suggests, regardless of `A/Z` and `B/Z` timestamps, only copy the file if `B/Z/foo` exists and is different from `A/Z/foo`?

Comment: Well hard to explain exactly but I what ONLY to copy IF A has newer timestamp then C for files that do ONLY exists in A, if they also exists in B instead check if newer from B in C otherwise do no copy at all for that file. The example I have here is only part of the whole solution, this is to copy only if not exists in B so to say.